# Compound Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $N_1 $ and $N_2 $ be independent Poisson processes with intensity $1 $ and $2$ respectively.

How to express $S=-2N_1 +N_2$ as a compound Poisson process?

Comment: What is $S$?          ____

Comment: There is "=" @PaoloLeonetti

Comment: I understand this is really about Poisson *processes*? Then try a constant intensity $3$ and some increments with distribution $P(X=-2)=\frac13$, $P(X=+1)=\frac23$.